# Connect Azure Data Factory to Logic App with credentials

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I have created an Azure Data Factory that calls Logic App via "Web" action.
Logic app is activated by HTTP request. My issue is, I have not idea, how can I secure logic app with API service (all manuals show JWT token) and then use authentication options from the web action

Please, do you have an idea, what is the easiest secured way to implement this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the IP address to access your logic app. Azure data factory now [supports static IP address ranges](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/20565967-static-ip-ranges-for-data-factory-and-add-adf-to-l), so you can [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-integration-runtime) an integration runtime. Then allow the IP address to request your logic app by setting as below:

[image]

Comment: thank you. but, how do I get IP address from it? I found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses but that means, that other data factories with different integration runtimes will share same IP addresses, right? is it safe?